# How to find the uncommon words from two files using only terminal commands in OSX?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, grep

I have two files of four letter words.

File A contains all possible combinations of four letter words. 
The words in this file, are one word per line, and are sorted like:

```
aaaa 
aaab 
aaac
  .
  .
aaba
aabb
```

File B contains "bad words". These are also in sorted order. The words in File B are a subset of File A. Each file has only unique words. There are no duplicates in a given file.

What is an efficient way to find only the "good words" in file A and save it in a second file from the terminal ?
I can easily write an Objective-C program using the following code:

```
//Omitted file handling code. Passing in both the files words as arrays.
-(NSMutableArray)goodWords:(NSMutableArray*)allWords badWords:(NSMutableArray*)badWords
{
  int ap = 0; int bp=0;
  NSMutableIndexSet *indices = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc]init];
  while(bp<badWords.count)
  {
     NSString* bs = [badWords objectAtIndex:bp];
     NSString* as = [allWords objectAtIndex:ap];
     if([as isEqualToString:bs])
     {
          //Make note of index containing bad word.
         [indices addIndex:ap];
         bp++; ap++; //Move both pointers ahead.
     }
     else
     {
       ap++; // Since both arrays are sorted, and the words don't match, I move the ap ahead. (since it is pointing at a "good word".
     }
  }
  //Make a copy of the original array of "good words".
  NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:allWords];
  [result removeObjectsAtIndexes:indices]; //Remove the bad words.
  [indices release];
  return result; 
}
```

Since these are lists of words, I can't use GREP. Is there a way to do this using only terminal commands in OSX ? I don't know where to begin with unix / terminal commands.

EDIT: Fixed a mistake in code;
EDIT: Added comments explaining algorithm.
EDIT: Made NSIndexSet NSMutableIndexSet;
EDIT: Accidentally typed AP instead of AllWords
EDIT: Fixed leak.

Comment: Well WRT your code, if `[goodWords count] > [badWords count]` (as you say it is) then your code will never see all of `goodWords`, so please provide a better Objective-C example (it doesn't even work properly).

Comment: No you haven't.  Firstly put them into an `NSSet` and then use `[goodWords minusSet:badWords]`.  Job done.  However that doesn't answer your question, but at least your example will make sense.

Comment: I think my example works - what is wrong with it?

Comment: I don't believe it will work, as what's pointed to by `bp` could exist in `goodWords` at an index less than `ap` (given it's a subset).  Use the code I provide and others will understand what you want better.

Comment: Well thats the point - its sorted, which is why I move ap ahead when there isn't a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you close:

```
$ cat goodwords 
aaaa
aaab
aaac
aaad
aaae

$ cat badwords 
aaaa
aaad

$ comm -3 goodwords badwords | grep -v '^\t$'
aaab
aaac
aaae
```

(the `grep` is there as `comm` uses tabs to separate "columns").

As an added bonus, your Objective-C version should store the values in an `NSSet` (as there are no dupes) and then use:

```
NSMutableSet *goodWords = [allWords mutableCopy];
[goodWords minusSet:badWords];
```